# How to get the param PK in django restframework permission?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have this permission in Django that look like this:

```
class PermissionName(BasePermission):
    

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        #I want to extract the pk or id params in here.

        return False
```

Can anybody help me get the params of request I tried using `self.kwargs["pk"]`, `request.POST['pk']` but they all return saying object has no attribute.

Comment: Since you are given the object, `obj.pk`?

Comment: pk or id of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pk` is a parameter of the POST request, you can access it with `request.POST.get('pk')`.  In your post, you are not using `get()`, so that could be the issue.

If the object is provided as an argument to the function, I'm assuming you want the ID of it.  That can also be achieved with `obj.id`.

Comment: I tried using the 'request.POST.get('pk')' but it displays nothing in Pdb.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one `pk` in your url and you use `has_object_permission` then.

```
class PermissionName(BasePermission):
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        obj.pk # To get object id.
```

But what if you have more then two `pk` in your url

```
urls.py

path("buildings/<int:pk>/units/<int:unit_pk>/")
```

Then you can get `pk's` from `view` attribute.

```
class PermissionName(BasePermission):
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print(view.kwargs)
```

Results:

`{'pk': 13, 'unit_pk': 71}`

Answer (score 1):

lets say your path is:

```
path('listings/get/category/<str:pk>/', endpoints.HousesWithSameCategory.as_view()),
```

Your request: `api/listings/get/category/1/`

In your class method view use:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    print(self.kwargs)
```

This will return `{'pk': '1'}`

`self.kwargs` will return all your dynamic params